# Writing SonarQube sensor plugin with support for multiple languages

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-runner

What is the correct way to add support for multiple programming languages to plugin?
Should a separate rules definition XMLs be loaded for each language with different repository keys and several implementations of *ProfileDefinition* created?

Is there an example of such plugin?

I am using SonarQube 5.2 snapshot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rule repositories and Quality profiles are associated to a single language, so multiple instances of `ProfileDefinition` and `RulesDefinition` must be provided.